# Nextjs app from html template external scripts not loaded correctly

Tags: next.js

I have a basic html template with javascript and css that I am building a nextjs app with. I am loading the javascript in '_document.js' file:

```
render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
```

The index.js page loads fine. The only link I have set up at the moment is to the about page. If you try clicking the about page link you will see that the javascript page loader never resolves. If you do a full refresh on the about page however it loads.

Has anyone encountered this and found a solution?

The github for the project:
https://github.com/nicolauria/next-balkon

The deployed application:
https://next-balkon.vercel.app/

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to install “loadjs” and load js files manually in “componentDidMount”.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/loadjs

I did this for every component where I needed the files and it worked for me
`componentDidMount() { loadJs(“/path/to/js/file.js”); }`